# How to adjust the position of dialog box at a specific position relative to the device in android

Tags: android, dialog

I have an android application in which there is a dialog box which opens up as a result of a button click.In this,i want to set the position of the dialog box just below the button.When i used verticalMargin,the position changes relative to the device when i tested in more than one devices with different screen resolution.What i need is that the dialog box should always appear just below the button irrespective of the screen size.